# Using two database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, mongodb

is it possible to use 2 types of database in a Rails application?

I am using 2 databases - **Postgres** to store data which might not change much, and **MongoDB** 
to store data which change dynamically.

is this valid approach? and is it possible to connect between these 2 databases and operate
in a single Rails application?

Please correct, if i am wrong.

regards,
Balan

Comment: Probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825844/multiple-databases-in-rails

Comment: By searching web i found a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825844/multiple-databases-in-rails
but the note specified mentions like sticking to single database first and establishing connection to second one using adapter..
but what i am trying is to have these 2 db configured in the Rails app so that i can do normal process like creating table with migration, updating table with Model etc.,

Comment: so are you saying this approach is not right? if so you can add this note in answer with relevant references.

Comment: Yes, I have done this and it is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found solution :**

We can use `mongoid` gem to achieve this.

**Steps to install**

1) Install mongoid by adding `"gem mongoid"` in Gemfile and running `bundle` command

2) Generate mongoid configuration by typing `"rails g mongoid:config"`, this will create a
   config file `mongoid.yml` near `database.yml` file, you can add the configuration to Mongo server
   in this file.

**Note :** After adding Mongoid, all the models created will be created for MongoDB by default, you can specify `--orm` option to generate Models for Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible here is an example from my old code (but here we use mysql for both the DB, but I think you can get an idea)

in database.yml file define two databases

```
development: &defaults
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: DB1
  enable_call: true
  username: 
  password: 
  host: 

portal_development: &defaults
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: DB2
  enable_call: true
  username: 
  password: 
  host:
```

in your models have to base models coupled with above databases

portal_base.rb

```
class PortalBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "portal_#{Rails.env}"

  def self.table_name_prefix
    "DB1."
  end
end
```

default_base.rb

```
class DefaultBase < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.abstract_class = true

  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}"

  def self.table_name_prefix
    "DB2."
  end

end
```

and derive your models accordingly

```
class Client < PortalBase
  #code
end
```

Hope you have an idea now :)

Comment: Is this possible only with Rails3?

Comment: didnt try, but should be possible