# Rails: Multiple databases, same schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-connection

I'm in the middle of a fictional scenario project where I have allowed multiple users for a company to log in, create records, and so on, who all connect to the one database. They can all records absence records, attendance records, and so on.

What I want to do however, is use this same schema but expands this to allow several **companies** to have their own databases using the same schema. So each company will have their own data, but all companies use the same data model. In other words all company's can create absence records, but they each only have access to their own absence records that they created themselves.

How can I achieve this?

All I need is two or three files for this, I'm not going commercial with it in case you guys think I'm cutting corners at someone else's expense!

Something as simple as an if-else that decides which file to use would be very useful to me, so if such a line of code exists please let me know.

Comment: This question will likely be closed since it's a bit too conceptual, does not specify which RDMS you are using and maybe better suited to one of the other stackexchange sites. However the term you are looking for here is `multitenancy`. Combine that term with `rails` and the name of your favourite RDMS and i'm sure you'll find some pointers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using SQLite3. Multitenancy popped up a few times in my searches by the way, I'll have a look into it. Thanks!

Comment: There would be [two great RailsCasts on Multitenacy](https://www.google.de/search?q=railscasts+multitenacy), both Pro episodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong (unless you have a really good reason to have a database for each company), because it seems like you are repeating your data model over and over while introducing unnecessary complexity to your code.

Try to have all the companies in one DB/tables with having separated by the `company_id`.

Ex: data  structure would be as follows

```
companies table
id
name


users table
id
user_name
company_id
```

However if you really want to connect to multiple databases, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825844/multiple-databases-in-rails).

Comment: That definitely seems like the easier option. Thanks for your answer! However, the project currently has many references to all models of a particular type (e.g. Absence.all). Is there any way I can scope all of this type of code by the company id in, say, the application controller, in a before filter? I only ask because otherwise I'm going to have a lot of refactoring to do...               EDIT: Just found this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class     In case anyone is wondering what I used to solve this problem. Thanks for the helps everyone!

Comment: As per the implementation I proposed, you will need to add some way of a relationship with `company` model (Ex: probably Absence model will have a user_id and User model will have a company_id), Then when u user logs in get his company_id to session and use it when required. (of course its little complex than this when it involves authorization and all)