# Multiple MySQL databases all using the same schema

Tags: mysql, data-modeling

EDIT: To clarify throughout this post: when I say "schema" I am referring to "data-model," which are synonyms in my head. :)

My question is very similar to this question ([Rails: Multiple databases, same schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821349/rails-multiple-databases-same-schema)), but mine is related to MySQL.

To reiterate the problem: I am developing a [SAAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service). The user will be given an option of which DB to connect to at startup. Most customers will be given two DBs: a production DB and a test DB, which means that every customer of mine will have 1-2 databases. So, if I have 10 clients, I will have about 20 databases to maintain. This is going to be difficult whenever the program (and datamodel) needs to be updated.

My question is: is there a way to have ONE datamodel for MULTIPLE databases? The accepted answer to the question I posted above is to combine everything into one database and use a company_id to separate out the data, but this has several foreseeable problems:

1. What happens when these transaction-based tables become inundated? My 1 customer right now has recorded 16k transactions already in the past month.
2. I'd have to add `where company_id =` to hundreds of SQL queries/updates/inserts ([yes, Jeff Atwood, they're Parametrized SQL calls](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)), which would have a severe impact on performance I can only assume.
3. Some tables store **metadata**, i.e., drop-down menu items that will be company-specific in some cases and application-universal in others. `where company_id =` would add an unfortunate layer of complexity.

It seems logical to me to create (a) new database(s) for each new customer and point their software client to their database(s). But, this will be a headache to maintain, so I'm looking to reduce this potential headache.

Answer (score 1):

Create scripts for deployments for change to the DB schema, keep an in house database of all customers and keep that updated, write that in your scripts to pull from for the connection string.

Way better than trying to maintain a single database for all customers if your software package takes off.

FYI: I am currently with an organization that has ~4000 clients, all running separate instances of the same database (very similar, depending on the patch version they are on, etc) running the same software package. A lot of the customers are running upwards of 20-25k transactions per second.

Comment: 25k transactions per second?

Comment: Yep this is exactly the way I'm doing it now.

Comment: Would be fantastic if you could elaborate on how you did that, a lot of us are struggling with this idea; Mainly (i think) because mysql doesn't support the (paraphrasing) 'create database like database' statement that postgreSQL has.

Answer (score 1):

1. A "database" in MySQL is called a "schema" by all the other database vendors. There are not separate databases in MySQL, just schemas.

   FYI: (real) databases cannot have foreign keys between them, whereas schemas can.
2. Your test and production databases should most definitely not be on the same machine.
3. Use Tenant Per Schema, that way you don't have company_ids in every table.
4. Your database schema should either be generated by your ORM or it should be in source control in sql files, and you should have a script that automatically builds/patches the db. It is trivial to change this script so that it builds a schema per tenant.

Comment: thank you. Yes I forget about the differences between `database` and `schema` in vernacular and in DMBS vocab. For clarification, when I say "schema," I'm really referring to "data-model." I think I'm going to edit the post to clarify that point. In my mind, "schema" is close to "schematic," so I think "schema" = "data-model."

Comment: Can you explain #2? Why not have test and production on the same machine? Production and backup, that I understand. But why can't the test DB be next to the production DB? #3, yes that was exactly my thinking. #4, yes, currently I just keep a "to-do.sql" file which I test on a DB and then execute on the prod/test DBs before deploying new versions. I just thought there might be an easier way.

Comment: Someone running tests on a test database might bring down the entire server. Or they might want to stress-test the database, which would make it unusable to others.

Comment: Hmm ok my fault. "Testing" is kind of a misnomer in this case. The "Test" DB is for clients to test features of the program, for training purposes and whatnot. I.E., my current client likes to create a lot of entities that he labels "TEST TRASH" on the live, production database. I have discouraged this behavior in favor of doing such things on the test database which is periodically wiped and loaded in with live data. Stress tests as it relates to development would be done on a separate "dev-test" database, on, yes, a different server. :)

Comment: This is why each client would two databases. A live DB and "test" DB, so they don't do any of their "TEST TRASH" shenanigans on the live data.

Comment: If by database you mean a different instance of MySQL (running on a different port), then you should be okay.