# Access Multiple database in Ruby on Rails using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am have a application where the user can chose the database which they to access.
I have to authenticate the user which the database they have chosen and i have to keep the transaction with thr user and the database till the user logs out.

I was able to do it by **establish_connection** and passing the database name requested by the user.
But i hit a **roadblock**.The issue is,

Lets assume **user1** requested to access the **databaseA** and the user has got the access not logged out,If **user2** requests to access **databaseB** , In that case even the **user1's** requests are hitting to **DatabaseB**

I am aware that **Devise** can solve this problem, I am not able to figure it out how.

Any suggestions would be really helpful

Comment: Post-authentication, will user access any other data? Are those data coming from same DB for all users or user-selected-DB for a given user?

Comment: Yes, Post authentication the user will access the data .For a given user, The data will be fetched from the user-selected DB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple databases in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825844/multiple-databases-in-rails)

Comment: Your problem is not limited to only `Devise` then.  Look at possible duplicate question [Multiple database in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825844/multiple-databases-in-rails)

Comment: @WandMaker
Thaks for the feedback... I was able to connect to multiple DB using magic multi connection , Below is the article,
http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_multi_connections/

But, I have to accomodate this change in devise ,But Devise always takes the default database ..Can you please help me out with this.

Comment: Not really a user of devise, may not be able to point to a solution currently