# How can I establish a connection to multiple databases, with the same adapter(postgres), using active_record gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, activerecord

how are you? I've been having some troubles when I try to establish a connection to two databases in postres. I will try to describe the scenario:

This is my pg.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  user: xxxxx
  password: xxxxx

development:
  <<: *default
  database: not_legacy

legacy:
  <<: *default
  database: legacy
```

This is my Legacy::Base class:

```
#/models/legacy/base.rb

require 'active_record'
require 'erb'

module Legacy
  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true

    conf_contents = File.read('config/pg.yml')
    conf_evaluated = ::ERB.new(conf_contents).result
    conf = YAML.load(conf_evaluated)

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection conf['legacy']
  end
end
```

and this is my NotLegacy::Base class:

```
#/models/not_legacy/base.rb

require 'active_record'
require 'erb'

module NotLegacy
  class Base < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.abstract_class = true

    conf_contents = File.read('config/pg.yml')
    conf_evaluated = ::ERB.new(conf_contents).result
    conf = YAML.load(conf_evaluated)

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection conf['not_legacy']
  end
end
```

Also, I have two classes that inherit from the classes previously described.
This is Legacy::Company:

```
#/models/legacy/company.rb    

require_relative 'base'

module Legacy
  class Company < Base
    self.table_name = "company"
  end
end
```

and NotLegacy::Company:

```
#/models/not_legacy/company.rb    

require_relative 'base'

module NotLegacy
  class Company < Base
    self.table_name = "company"
  end
end
```

Now, if I go to the console and do something like(I'm printing conf value):

```
irb(main):001:0> load 'app/models/legacy/company.rb'
CONFS: {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "host"=>"localhost", "user"=>"xxxxx", "password"=>"xxxxx", "database"=>"legacy"}
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Legacy::Company.count
=> 8
irb(main):003:0> load 'app/models/not_legacy/company.rb'
CONFS: {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "host"=>"localhost", "user"=>"xxxxx", "password"=>"xxxxx", "database"=>"not_legacy"}
=> true
irb(main):004:0> NotLegacy::Company.count
=> 1
```

At this point everything seems to work correctly since in the **legacy** database there are **8 records** for company and in the **not_legacy** database there is only **1 record**. But if I call Legacy::Company again, I get:

```
irb(main):005:0> Legacy::Company.count
=> 1
irb(main):005:0> NotLegacy::Company.count
=> 1
```

It seems that the second connection (made to the not_legacy database) is **overwriting** the first one (the one made to the legacy database).

If anyone of you can explain me why this is happening and how to fix it I will be immensely grateful

Thanks.

Comment: please have a look, I guess you will get your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832441/3445936

Comment: @rohit Yes, I guess it is perfect reference, but rails can handle multiple database but switching is little difficult.

Comment: I would suggest looking into open source gems like [octopus](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus) or [active_record_shards](https://github.com/zendesk/active_record_shards) because of the thread safety issues and complexity involved in writing your own sharding logic.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to go with basic about how you are going through code flow,

When you load any class, its code is executed & methods defined, your connection is created through static code written & `establish_connection` is executed.

**Single instant of rails app can have connection to single database**

You better to write code to switch through different database to have access for different database connectivity.

`Legacy::Company` or `NotLegacy::Company` both models have same table name `companies` from different databases. But when you connect particular database both model (which got loaded) will point to `companies` table in current database.

`So what is current database mean to both model ?` 
 -> The one which is loaded last time by `establish_connection`.

So this is little tedious but it is working that if you deal with different databases, you have to keep switching from one database to another one.

Answer (score 0):

on config/database.yml

```
other_base:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  user: xxxxx
  password: xxxxx
```

on your model

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.establish_connection :other_base
end
```